# I am trying to create a program that averages numbers, but cannot figure out how to add the user inputted numbers together

Tags: java

I am an AP Computer Science student learning Java. I learned JavaScript prior to taking this course, but I am having trouble figuring out how to complete this code. My teacher is on leave, and our sub is not a programmer. I appreciate any help. My teacher wants us to put comments explaining everything. 
Here is my code:

```
package com.company;
```

//imports the scanner class and any other importable class needed

import java.util.*;

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Asks a question and lets the user input an answer, saved as the int Dividend
    System.out.println("How many numbers do you want to average?");
    Scanner dividend = new Scanner(System.in);
    int Dividend = dividend.nextInt();

    //this is a variable set in order to make the while statement work for any number
    int change = 0;

    //Asks for the numbers that should be averaged
    System.out.println("Enter the numbers to find their average: ");

    /*This is saying that while change is less than the amount of numbers being averaged,
      continue to provide an input for numbers*/
    while (change <= Dividend) {
        int Num = 0;
        int nums = 0;
        Scanner num = new Scanner(System.in);
        //I am trying to add the input to num so I can average them
        nums = num.nextInt();
        Num += nums;
        /*this is making sure that change is letting the code run through the exact amount of necessary times
          in order to input the correct amount of numbers*/
        change++;

        //once all of the numbers have been put in, average them
        if (change == Dividend) {
            System.out.println("Average: " + Num / Dividend);
        }
        System.out.println(Num);
    }


}
```

}

Comment: Can you explain what change is?

Comment: Also what Dividend is its not declared

Comment: Sorry some of my code did not copy, here is the full code:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed yours so it adds all the numbers now still not sure what half of it does I added `nums = nums + num.nextInt();` so it will total all nums

I created my solution as well if you want a working reference on the bottom below yours

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int change = 0;//Total Numbers It think
    int nums = 0;//Sum

    System.out.println("Enter the numbers to find their average: ");
    Scanner num = new Scanner(System.in);//Should be moved out of loop so its not initialized every time

    int Dividend=1;//I had to declare to run it
    while (change <= Dividend) {//not sure why your comparing these

        nums = nums + num.nextInt();//Total Sum
        change++;//Total nums

        if (change == Dividend) {
            System.out.println("Average: " + nums / Dividend);
        }
        System.out.println(nums);
    }
}
```

Here is what i would do

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int sum = 0;
    int countOfNumbers = 0;//Tthe same as your change im guessing

    System.out.println("Enter the numbers to find their average type stop to quit: ");//Added stop statement
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);//Should be moved out of loop so its not initialized everytime

    while (scanner.hasNext()){//Ensures there is something to check
        String next = scanner.next(); //Pull next Value
        if(next.equalsIgnoreCase("Stop"))//This will prevent looping forever
            break;
        sum = sum + Integer.valueOf(next); //Get total sum
        countOfNumbers++; //Increment total numbers
        System.out.println("The Sum is:"+sum
                +"\nThe count of Numbers averaged is:"+countOfNumbers
                +"\nThe Average is:"+sum/countOfNumbers);//Print info 
    }
    System.out.println("Done Averaging Goodbye");
}
```

Comment: I looked back through my code and figured out the problem using your reference as a guide, I was initializing the scanner every time the loop ran like you said, and I was resetting  the variable Num to 0 every time. I have no idea why I included nums but anyways, thank you very much for the help.

Comment: No problem anymore questions let me know but also if you could accept the answer by clicking the check next to the question so others do not think this question is still open

Comment: Also take a look at java naming conventions here is a reference https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-naming-conventions/ I noticed some capitalized variables

Answer (score -1):

You could use an `ArrayList` to store all of the user inputs and later iterate through it to average them.